# Elixir Xmpp Ejabberd ejabberd_c2s.open_session function arguments?

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I am trying open a new session in ejabberd xmpp server by the command...

:ejabberd_c2s.open_session(%{user: "test2", server: "localhost", resource: "tkae1", sid: 6, ip: "localhost", auth_module: "shaper"})
But it giving error that no function_clause matching function ejabberd_c2s.changeshaper/1 .

What is the correct format of argument that I need to send to ejabberd_c2s.open_session function.

The open_session function's definition in ejabberd_c2s module is as follows:
open_session(#{user := U, server := S, resource := R,sid := SID, ip := IP, auth_module := AuthModule} = State)

Answer (score 0):

The State you provide to open_session is later passed to change_shaper. And change_shaper expects some other fields in the State, look at its definition: shaper and lserver.